# Prove that $a$ and $b$ are coprime whenever $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I wish to prove that if $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime, then $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

I want to make sure that my proof holds, so any reasonable insight concerning this problem would be appreciated.

Suppose $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime where $a$ and $b$ are integers. Then for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $n = \pm 1$, we have $n|(a+b)$ and $n|(a-b)$, which implies that

$$a+b = nk \tag{1}$$
$$a-b = nj \tag{2}$$

for some $k,j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, equation $(1)$ implies that $b = nk-a$, from which equation $(2)$ becomes $a = nj + b = nj + (nk-a)$. Adding $a$ to both sides of the equation and factoring the $n$, we have the equation

$$2a = n(k+j)$$

But if we divide both sides by $2$, we have

$$a = n \cdot \frac{k+j}{2}$$

Since we are assuming that $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $n \cdot \frac{k+j}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ (in particular, $\frac{k+j}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$). Therefore, $n| a$. A similar argument can be made to show that $n|b$.

**Updated Portion**

Now assume there is another integer $d$ that divides $a$ and $b$. Consequently, we have the following equations

$$a = dk$$
$$b = dj$$

for some $k,j \in \mathbb{N}$.

If we add and subtract the two equations, we have

$$a+b = d(k+j)$$
$$a-b = d(k-j)$$

so $d|(a+b)$ and $d|(a-b)$. But $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime, so we must have $d=n$. Therefore, $n =\pm 1$ is the only integer that divides $a$ and $b$.

Hence $a$ and $b$ are coprime under the assumption that $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: All this proves is that $n$ divides both $a,b$.  Since $n=\pm 1$, this isn't much use.

Comment: @vadim123 But if $n$ is the only integer that divides both $a+b$ and $a-b$, and it has been shown that $n$ also divides both $a$ and $b$, why does it not follow that $a$ and $b$ are coprime?

Comment: @user236182 Thank you; corrected it.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire Indeed it has been shown that $n$ divides both $a,b$, but you haven't proved that there are no integers larger than $n$ that divide both $a,b$.

Comment: @user236182 That's a good point. So, I would assume that another integer $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, which implies that $a = dk$ and $b = dj$. Upon adding the equations, I get $a+b = d(k+j)$. Since $a+b$ is prime, it follows that $d = \pm 1$. Thus $a$ and $b$ are coprme.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire $a+b$ is not necessarily prime.

Comment: @user236182 Oh, yeah, that's true, too. Do you have any suggestions on how to prove this result without appealing to the solutions provided in the two answers below?

Comment: @user236182 What if in the spirit of what I proposed in my earlier reply, we show that $d$ divides both $a+b$ and $a-b$. Then since $a+b$ and $a-b$ are coprime, $d$ must equal $n$. And since we are assuming that $d$ divdes $a$ and $b$, we can conclude that the only integers that divide both $a$ and $b$ are $\pm 1$, so $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire That is actually a correct idea, and one that I used in my edited answer. It's easier to prove the contrapositive.

Comment: @user236182 I know, but I wanted to see if a direct proof would work just the same. It's neat to see different ways to prove the same proposition, and I wanted to try and avoid an indirect proof if possible, just to see if I could.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire I've edited the answer. Your idea is essentially the direct proof I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrapositive proof: If $k\mid a,b$ for some $k\ge 2$, then $k\mid a+b, a-b$.

Direct proof: Let $\gcd(a+b,a-b)=1$ and $k\mid a,b$. Then $k\mid a+b, a-b$, so $k\mid \gcd(a+b,a-b)=1$, so $k=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler approach: $\gcd(a,b)=(a,b)=1$ if and only if there are integers $j,k\in\Bbb Z$ with $aj+bk=1$. Thus, since $(a+b,a-b)=1$, there are integers $j,k\in\Bbb Z$ so that $(a+b)j+(a-b)k=1$, but this is the same as $(j+k)a+(j-k)b=1$. Since $j+k,j-k\in\Bbb Z$, we have that $(a,b)=1$.